# How do I evaluate whether the first three characters of a string are all ALPHA in Snowflake?

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The value of my field is `'VNF123'`.

My line of code is `left(field,3) regexp '^[A-Z]{3}'`

It returns `FALSE`

I tried a literal:  `'VNF' regexp '^[A-Z]{3}'`

And it returns `TRUE`

Comment: Don't know much about Snowflake,  but you don't actually need the left function.  Your regexp should return true whether or not there are any characters after the first three letters.

Comment: That doesn't seem to hold true - it wants me to provide a pattern for the entire string - it would only seem to work if I included a wildcard after indicating the first 3 characters are alpha.  Lots of trial and error but the issue I listed above, I can't seem to figure out.  For example, @ChrisMaurer, I tried the literal:  'VNF123' regexp '^[A-Z]{3}' and that evaluates FALSE.  Weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there was some kind of control character in the first position of my string.  When I added left(ltrim(field),3) regexp '^[A-Z]{3}' - it evaluated TRUE as expected.

Answer (score 0):

[REGEX](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp.html) is an alias to [RLIKE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/rlike.html), which take parameters verse the in the middle form of REGEXP so I have gone for that:

But core thing to know is in snowflake some of the REPEXP function have implicit anchor tokens `^`,`$` added to them, a [REPEXP/RLIKE is one of them](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/rlike.html#usage-notes):

thus:

```
select 
    column1 as field
    ,left(field,3) as l_field
    ,rlike(field, '^[A-Z]{3}') as r1
    ,rlike(l_field, '^[A-Z]{3}') as r2
    ,rlike(field, '^[A-Z]{3}.*') as r3
from values
    ('VNF123'),
    ('VNF'),
    ('NF123')
    ;
```

gives:

| FIELD | L_FIELD | R1 | R2 | R3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VNF123 | VNF | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE |
| VNF | VNF | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| NF123 | NF1 | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |

which shows the third row always fails as expected, and the second always passes, but the first passes when the pattern takes this implicit anchor into account.

thus the solution is to add a `.*` to match the tail, and you are away laughing.

```
field regexp '^[A-Z]{3}.*'
```

Comment: The implicit anchor information is definitely helpful.  But my question remains - why would rlike(left(field,3),'^[A-Z]{3}') return a FALSE?  That is the problem that I am having when the value in field = 'VNF123'.  But I turn around and test rlike('VNF','^[A-Z]{3}') and it evaluates TRUE.

Comment: in my example it doesn't return false. `select rlike(left('VNF123',3),'^[A-Z]{3}');` is true